# How to delete rows of multiple text files based on string list from another file?

Tags: powershell

I have multiple comma delimited text files (each has over 1 million rows). Also I have one file called "delete.log" .

Structure of delete.log file is like this:

```
STRING1   
STRING2   
STRING3  
.  
.   
STRING N
```

Structure one of many txt files is like this:
name1.txt :

```
text1,text2,text3,text4,STRING1            "entire row will be deleted" 
text1,text2,text3,text4,STRING1            "entire row will be deleted"
text1,text2,text3,text4,text5              
text1,text2,text3,text4,STRING2            "entire row will be deleted"     
text1,text2,text3,text4,STRING1            "entire row will be deleted"
text1,text2,text3,text4,text5
```

I'm looking for a effective way how to read each text string from file "delete.log" and if there is a match in row 5 with text string from delete.log file,
entire row will be deleted.
Also if there is a text file in a folder with a file name from delete.log 
like STRING1.txt, file will be deleted.

This code below just delete entire row from multiple text files if text string in column 5 is STRING1

```
$paths = Get-ChildItem '.\' -Filter '*.txt'
ForEach ($path in $paths) {
$pathtmp = "$path.tmp"

$sr = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $path
$sw = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $pathtmp

Do {
 $line = $sr.ReadLine()
 $Column =  $line.split(",")


If ($Column[4] -ne "STRING1")  {
    $sw.WriteLine($line)
}
} Until ( $sr.EndOfStream )

$sr.close()
$sw.close()

Remove-Item $path
Rename-Item $pathtmp $path
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the files using the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmldet, use the [Select-String](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) cmdlet to filter the entries and finally write the entries back using [Set-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113392):

```
$deleteLog = Get-Content 'delete.log'
$name1 = Get-Content 'name1.txt'

$name1 | Select-String -NotMatch $deleteLog | Set-Content 'name1.txt'
```

Content of `name1.txt` now:

```
text1,text2,text3,text4,text5              
text1,text2,text3,text4,text5
```

Comment: As I mentioned above. I have multiple txt files with over 1 million rows each. I would like to keep my code as fast as possible. That's why I'm using System.IO.StreamReader and System.IO.StreamWriter. I'm not sure if your solution would be very effective.

Comment: I would like to implement something like this into my code :  foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filename)) {
    // do something with $line
}  If it is possible.